# react image upload to ASP.NET error 404 (controller never called?)

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, rest, axios

I'm learning asp.net after using Django for years so I might be missing something really easy for you all.

I need to upload an image using react, compute some metrics of the image (don't have to save it in the server) then return those metrics using a JSON object.

So far I'm trying using this code but I only get error 404.

React component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export class DetectObject extends Component {
    displayName = DetectObject.name

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedFile : null, 
            items: [],
            loading: true,
        };
    }

    fileUploadHandler = () => {
        const fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('image', this.state.selectedFile, this.state.selectedFile.name);
        axios.post('api/Image/Upload', fd)
            .then(response => { console.log(response); });
    }

    fileSelectedHandler = event => {
        this.setState({ selectedFile: event.target.files[0] });
    }

    render() {
        let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            : <p>The content was loaded</p>;

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Object Detection</h1>
                <p>Load an image.</p>
                <input type="file" onChange={this.fileSelectedHandler} /><br/>
                <button onClick={this.fileUploadHandler}>Upload Image</button><br/>
                {contents}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

ImageController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace AspObjectDetection.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ImageController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(IFormFile file)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello from controller Image");
            if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
                throw new Exception("File is empty!");

            return Content("hello world!"+file.FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

It is not even printing the "hello from image controller" message. Is it something wrong with my controller? Is my controller ever called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your method using `FromFormAttribute`

**Edited**

```
 [HttpPost("[action]")]
 public ActionResult Upload([FromForm] IFormFile file)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("hello from controller Image");
    if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
    throw new Exception("File is empty!");

    return Content("hello world!"+file.FileName);
 }
```

Comment: I added this [HttpPost("[action]")] and now is working, thank you Alexandre, I'm also gonna add the [FromForm] annotation since that wouldn't hurt. Gonna select your answer as the solution since my comment is in the same thread.

Comment: @EduardoA.FernándezDíaz Glad that you solved the issue. I have edited the answer as you used `[HttpPost("[action]")]` to solve it.